# Strongswan: Transport mode with non-specific remote hosts

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I am using strongSwan 5.2.1 on Debian Jessie, and am having trouble configuring it to do what I want.

**Premise**

In a test environment, I am seeking to use transport mode IPsec between a Linux virtual machine, and a Windows virtual machine configured as an FTP server in active mode. The IPsec will be applied *only* to FTP traffic; that is, traffic to/from TCP ports 20 and 21 on the Windows VM. All other traffic between the two hosts (e.g. pings) should be unencrypted.

In the real-world scenario I am doing this for, the FTP server's IP address will vary, thus I would like my strongSwan configuration to not have to reference a specific remote IP.

**ipsec.conf file on Linux**

Contents are as follows:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file
# basic configuration
config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueid =  no
# Add connections here.
include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc
conn main
    type=transport
    left=%any
    right=10.1.1.2
    leftauth=psk
    rightauth=psk
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024
    esp=3des-sha1
    keyexchange=ikev1

conn data
    also=main
    rightsubnet=%dynamic[6/20]
    auto=route

conn command
    also=main
    rightsubnet=%dynamic[6/21]
    auto=route
```

**The Issue**

The IPsec.conf above does everything I want to do, except that the FTP server's IP address is specified in the file by the line `right=10.1.1.2`.

The `also=route` parameter means that the key exchange is only initiated when traffic is detected going to/from `10.1.1.2` on TCP ports 20 or 21. I want a configuration that initiates key exchange to **any IP address** when traffic is detected going to/from that address' TCP ports 20 and 21.

Is such a configuration possible in strongSwan, and if not, is there any other keying daemon for Linux that can do what I want to achieve?

**Additional Notes**

- Setting `right=%any` does not achieve what I want. This setting allows any remote host to initiate a key exchange with the local host; it does not mean that the local host will initiate a key exchange with any remote host.
- The Windows host's IPsec configuration is set to use `Any IP Address` on both ends of the connection, and successfully behaves in the way that I want.
- The use of IKEv1 in my configuration is for legacy compatibility.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To use `right=%any` with transport mode trap policies (i.e. `auto=route`) you need at least [strongSwan 5.3.3](https://wiki.strongswan.org/versions/58). Refer to the [ikev2/trap-any](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/trap-any/) scenario for an example.